# Use a language specific thousand separator

Tags: formatting, localization

I have a views counter on each post. When it reaches for example 1000, it adds a dot as the thousand separator, the result is 1.000. This is odd in my language, I should have a space as separator or nothing.

How can I change that?!

Answer (score 5):

Use [`number_format_i18n( $number )`](http://queryposts.com/function/number_format_i18n/). It will format the number with respect to the current blog’s language setting. It is a wrapper for [PHP’s native `number_format()`](http://php.net/number-format).

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped, but to fix this I had to change wp-includes/functions.php.

Comment: No, that’s wrong. The language separator is probably just missing in your language files. Add it there, do not create a fork of WordPress just for this.